# What data structure does the C runtime use to store information about variable like type size etc?

Tags: c, runtime

what data structure does the c runtime use to store information about variable like type, size etc

ex:

```
void foo(){
  int bar=0, goo=44;
  int*q, *p = &goo;
  //some code follows

  bar = goo + bar*9; 
  ...
  q=p;
  ... 
}
```

In the above code we have local variable bar and goo which will be allocated on stack when control reaches the foo function. But how will runtime determine at later point, when these variables are referenced, that these variables are of so and so type and of so and so size ?

Comment: type checking and determining places where variables are referenced is handled by the compiler before runtime. Variables are generally stored in a data structure called a symbol table, which will contain information like address in memory, type, value, etc...

Comment: @JeeZ: why do you believe such runtime information is needed? C doesn't have any reflection features, doesn't do garbage collection, etc. so why would the type of a variable be needed during runtime?

Comment: @gfour I come from .Net background so was under the assumption that these  information will be available to runtime

Comment: C is a compiled language.  It doesn't have a runtime environment like Java or C#.  C code is compiled to machine code and executed.  There's no encapsulating managed environment around it.

Comment: There is one situation where a C implementation must store runtime information about variable sizes, and that's VLAs from C99. For those, the answer to the question is, "it's entirely up to the implementation how it does it", but I think most plausible is that it sticks the number somewhere on the stack (almost as if it was an extra variable along with any others in that function), and that no more finesse is needed than that. There might a struct on the stack containing the size of the VLA and a pointer to its first element, though.

Comment: Or come to think of it, since there's are types "pointer to VLA", maybe the size is best stored immediately preceding the first element. Anyway, the point is that it's completely implementation-specific, and there's no portable way that a C program can access it directly. You just get the size of the VLA with `sizeof` and ignore the implementation details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime does not keep any such information - it is compiled into the binary code the compiler generates as constants. The compiler knows the size of each type, so it knows how to generate proper machine code for cleaning up the stack, accessing array elements, accessing fields of the struct, et cetera. There is no need to keep this information around at runtime, because the binary code already contains all the appropriate instructions.

Comment: ...and yes, in case you were wondering, that is part of the reason why C is so fast :)

Answer (score 3):

Variable sizes are known in compile time, so there is no need to keep them at runtime.

```
int bar = 0;
```

simply translates to

```
"shift the stack pointer by 4 bytes"
```

Variable types are neither needed to be known at all at runtime. You may get compiler warnings about incompatible types, like printing `int` with `%c`, but this is more of a sanity check for you. A variable simply names a chunk of data and it is up to you how to interpret them - as an integer, as a pointer, as 4 chars...

Answer (score 3):

Generally such is hard coded in the underlying machine code at compile time and there is no such data kept at runtime.

As an example, suppose the variable bar is placed on the stack. The compiler will remember where on the stack it was placed and all subsequent references to bar will become machine code which grabs the size of the variable at the relevant stack offset. The same is true for variables held in processor registers, references to them will convert into machine code which accesses the appropriate register and byte length.

Comment: So i believe, same is the case with even pointer p which will be pointing to goo on stack but the exact address where the pointer p will point is determined when the binary is loaded and executed ?

Comment: @JeeZ Yes that is correct, in that case the way the machine code grabs the variable is determined from the pointer type. The actual type information of the pointer is not kept at runtime, but rather at compile time the compiler translates all uses of the pointer into relevant machine code for manipulating data of that size and type, just like a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows this information for it's configured platform. The compiler also has C include header files to tell it the size of various data types. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h)

Comment: stdint.h does not tell the compiler the size of types; rather it provides aliases for the built-in types that make the size clear to humans, and the code portable amongst compilers with different sized basic types.  They are also commonly used when addressing memory mapped registers and I/O where the sizes are defined in hardware.  Either way it is still static not runtime type information.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Clifford.